# Is it possible to always have full autocompletion in Qt Creator?(like ctrl-space)

Tags: qt-creator

Is there any possibility to have forced auto completion (for all text, not only :: -> etc) always active in Qt creator 4.7 ?

Answer (score 0):

I use the 2.1 git branch, and if you wait a bit when typing eg. a class member inside the definition of a member function of that class, it will pop up in a little window. I can press enter and it's filled in automatically.